# easyXDM without Flash

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, internet-explorer-10, easyxdm

We are evaluating easyXDM for reading 3rd party cookies with http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/sending-and-receiving-messages/ (i.e. following socket based messages).

We have observed that easyXDM uses flash for communication. I would appreciate your letting me know that would easyXDM will continue to work on browser or system that do NOT have flash plugin installed.

Also, we understand that newer version on Windows 8 would not officially support flash therefore if any new user having windows 8 without flash installed with browser, would easyXDM continue to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easyxdm has multiple transport streams, and uses flash for only one of them (for ie 6 and 7 support).  I suggest you read https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM#readme and dig through it's documentation a little more.

And windows 8 ships with two browsers. One that supports external plugins (like flash) and one that does not.